# RSA encryption key conditions

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-generation

I recently read the RSA cryptosystem but now I confused in key generation phase.
According to the Euler's Theorem, we have just one condition:

> e.d = k.ϕ(N) + 1

where:

- "e" is encryption key.
- "d" is decryption key.
- "N" is a number in form of p*q where p and q are both primes.
- "ϕ(N)" is equal to (p-1)(q-1).

But some of documentations states new conditions as:

> 1. e should be small.
> 2. gcd(φ(N),e)=1.
> 3. e should be an odd number

Now, My question is why I should satisfy these 3 conditions?

I think the second and third conditions are stated just to ensure that **"d"** is an integer too because of `d =  (k.φ(N) + 1)/e`. Am I correct?

And finally, I think the first conditions is stated to make sure that **"d"** is enough large. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why I should satisfy these ?
>
> 1. $e$ should be small.

There's 3 reasons

- It's in the interest of speed of the public-key operations (encryption and signature verification), which in RSA take time roughly proportional to $\log e$.
- It ensures compatibility with some implementations, which limit $e$ to 32 (or is it 31) bits.
- It makes it impossible to use a small $d$, which would ruin security. The question's final paragraph is right about that.

Notice that for mostly historical reasons, you'll also find recommendations that $e$ is not too small. Definitely, $e\le1$ would be a terrible idea. At the end of the day, the most common and unobjectionable is $e=F_4=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$, where $F_4$ is the largest known [Fermat prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_prime).

> 2. $\gcd(\varphi(N),e)=1$.

In this, $\varphi(N)$ differs only in notation from $\phi(N)$ or is it $\Phi(N)$ in the question's  "$\phi(N)$ is equal to $(p-1)(q-1)$". That's the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). $\varphi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$ holds when $N=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ *distinct* primes, which is overwhelmingly likely when $p$ and $q$ are primes chosen randomly enough.

And $\gcd(\varphi(N),e)=1$ is necessary for existence of (integers) $k$ and $d$ such that $e\cdot d=k\cdot\varphi(N)+1$.

> $e$ should be an odd number.

Unless $p$ or $q$ is $2$, which would be a bad idea, that follows from $e\cdot d = k\cdot(p-1)(q-1)+1$.

> I think the second and third conditions are stated just to ensure that $d$ is an integer too because of $d=(k\cdot\varphi(N)+1)/e$.

Uh, no. Integers and bitstrings are about the only data representations in cryptography, and in RSA they are often assimilated per [big-endian convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so everything is an integer.

That exists $k$ with $e\cdot d=k\cdot\varphi(N)+1$ or (equivalently) $d=(k\cdot\varphi(N)+1)/e$ can be noted $d\equiv e^{-1}\pmod{\varphi(N)}$, and that means $d$ is (an integer representative of) the inverse of $e$ in the [multiplicative group of the integers modulo $\varphi(N)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Comment: Thank you! You made it clear completely.